# cfqueryparam date greater than or equal to

Tags: oracle, coldfusion

I am using Oracle and I have a select query where I want to select from the Inventory table with Year greater than or equal to year 2000.

```
Select * from Inventory
where 
manufac_date >=  <cfqueryparam value="01/01/2000" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_DATE">
```

I am getting only those values with year greater than 2000, but not those from year 2000.

Any comments or suggestions please?

Comment: What do you get if you use `manufac_date > <cfqueryparam value="12/31/1999" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_DATE">`? If it's the same I'd suspect your data.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Oracle is different. But as long as it recognizes `cf_sql_date`, and not just `cf_sql_timestamp`, I see no reason it should not work. Are you *positive* :

1. the table contains records for that period
2. those records are not being excluded by some other condition
3. that you are actually using `>=` and not just `>`

Answer (score 1):

You should either make your cfqueryparam value a date object

```
manufacDateFilter = createDate(2000, 1 , 1);
```

in the query then you have

```
where
manufac_date >= <cfqueryparam value="#manufacDateFilter#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_DATE">
```

or use Oracle's to_date function like so (not tested, but should work)

```
manufac_date >= to_date(<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="01/01/2000">,'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Comment: Agreed that one should not use a string for date operations, one should use a date.  Fransis should not be storing their date values as strings; they should be dates.

Comment: No doubt datetime objects are preferable. But CF should parse that particular U.S. date string into the same date value. Which makes you wonder if something else is going on ..

Comment: Dealing with dates in databases in general is not the easiest thing, to begin with. Especially Oracle turns out to be very picky when it comes to implizit date conversion. Using to_date() or to_char() is always a good idea and can save you lot of work and trouble. Another option would be to use ISO Date Format (2010-12-31) which is  correctly converted across most (all?) database engines.

Comment: Why do you say there would be implicit conversion *in Oracle*? Since they are using `cf_sql_date`, implicit conversion happens on the CF side before anything is ever sent to Oracle. CF uses US date format rules to convert the string `"01/01/2000"` to a date/time object `{ts '2000-01-01 00:00:00'}`. Then sends the date/time object to Oracle. So there should not be any implicit conversion in Oracle. I agree relying on implicit conversion (at all) can be problematic. But in this specific case, I do not see the issue. Unless maybe it is a peculiarity of Oracle ..? I do not use it much.